# Communicating with Node.js server code on Compute Engine using socket.io and C# client

Tags: c#, sockets, google-app-engine, socket.io, google-compute-engine

I currently have a Compute Engine and App Engine working and a C# client application.
My goal is to connect my C# client app with google cloud and work real-time with requests and websocket.

For that purpose, after reading lots of documentations and guides, I decided to go with this logic:

- Send requests to App Engine,
- listen App Engine with Compute Engine and then
- send response to C# app with Compute Engine, using websocket connection.

And for that, I tried using `socket.io` without any luck.

Issue here is my `mydomain.appspot.com` url is working fine, at least it shows a text without any change.

I get `Listening port xxxx` on my terminal, yet no changes occur.

I feel like I'm listening to something but not actually connected to it so code under `.connect` doesn't run.

- What should I do to work this out?
- Am I misunderstanding the concept?
- I added a firewall rule on port 65080, which is the one I'm using.

I'm getting `Port is in use` error (Exit status code 8 error, but I looked it up and it means that) when I listen to whatever port, yet when I show active processes on that port, there are none.

Are there any additional configurations should I make on the Google Cloud part, other than the ones in official Bookshelf tutorial?

**Server Code**

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(65080);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var address = socket.handshake.address;
  console.log('New connection from ' + address.address + ':' + address.port);

io.sockets.emit('this', { will: 'be received by everyone'});

socket.on('private message', function (msg) {
console.log('New Chat Message ', msg);
io.sockets.emit('txt',msg);
});

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
io.sockets.emit('User Disconnected');
});

socket.on('newuser', function (name) {
console.log(name,' Is Now Connected!');
io.sockets.emit('txnpm start
                t',name + ' is now online');
});

socket.on('exit', function (name) {
console.log(name,' Has Been Disconnected!');
io.sockets.emit('txt',name + ' is now offline');
});
});
```

**Client Code**

```
 Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        user = "x";
        MyForm = new Form1();
        temp = new Form2();
        Application.Run(temp);
        try
        {
            socket = new Client(ip.ToString());
            socket.On("txt", (data) =>
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(data.RawMessage);
                String msg = data.Json.Args[0].ToString();
                Console.Write(msg);
                MyForm.update(msg);
                //MessageBox.Show(msg, "Received Data");
            });
            socket.Connect();
             }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(),"Something Went Wrong!!");
            Application.Exit();
        }
        if (socket.ReadyState.ToString() == "Connecting")
        {
            userset();
            Application.Run(MyForm);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed To Connect To Server!", "Error!");
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

**&&**

```
    using (var ws = new WebSocketSharp.WebSocket("ws://104.197.217.126:65080/"))
        {
            ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
              MessageBox.Show(e.Data);

            ws.Connect();               
        }
```

**EDIT:**

Also tried a different approach on client side by following the client Android code provided by socket.io, just to make sure if the issue was with my C# client code. Still no result, same situation persists.

**Android Client Code**

```
Socket mSocket;
Activity activity;
     public void  connect(Activity a){
     activity=a;

         try {
             mSocket = IO.socket("http://104.197.217.126:65080");
         } catch (URISyntaxException e) {}

         mSocket.on("new message", onNewMessage);
         mSocket.connect();

        //  mSocket.emit("new message", "sadasdasd");
     }

private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {

    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                String username;
                String message;
                try {
                    username = data.getString("username");
                    message = data.getString("message");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    return;
                }
                // add the message to view
                Toast.makeText(activity,username+"-"+message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: On what port are you trying to connect? `1337` and you started the socket on `65080`?

Comment: @Shaharyar oh sorry. I pasted the wrong snippet. Yes I'm also using 65080 there.

Comment: I hope you're using correct IP instead of `127.0.0.1`. Also remove **/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=websocket** from the URL. Just connect to **hostip:port**

Comment: @Shaharyar yes I'm using the external IP provided for my Compute Engine Instance instead of that. Yet, i think removing that part from the url wouldn't help, since socket.io requires that part for connections. I think I even tried doing the same before without any luck.

Comment: Why don't you use actual client written for C# http://socketio4net.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: @Shaharyar I read somewhere that this guide won't work for newer socket.io versions. Also, it says that it's no longer maintained as of 2014

Comment: How far does your client code get? What does the client output? Could you clarify a bit more what relation holds between App Engine and Compute Engine here? Where is the C# code running? Could you draw a diagram or explain the order of events?

Comment: @Nick sorry for late response. Both client and server goes into connect methods and stay there. Handshake does not occur. Server is listening and client is trying to connect without any success. C# code is running on bunch of devices, it's like a computer application. And I unfortunately don't know what exactly is the relationship between GAE and GCE. I followed Google's guides and it said that I needed to use combination of GAE and GCE in order to use websocket connections. Also the external IP of GCE instance can be opened on browser, as a blank page, if that heps. I also added firewall rule

Comment: @Nick added an edit to my question, providing another effort on the client side in order to connect, no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In conclusion, these are the steps I took:

- Created a Compute Engine instance, installed node and other modules needed
- Used the code I added to my question on the server side. For this, I first added my Node.js project to GitHub, then deployed it to my Compute Engine instance by simply connecting with SSH and using git clone http://github.com/username/repname.git
- Then, in my projects directory, I started the .js file by using "node app.js" and it went into idle state, waiting for connections. This is all for the server side.
- For the client side, I was using wrong libraries. I needed to use the socket.io client library to interact with my socket.io server app. So I used [this](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet) library for my C# client app, but you can use other socket.io libraries for different languages.
- My code for client app looks like this:

  ```
   var socket = IO.Socket("http://104.198.214.221:65080"); 
   // this ip has to be your instance's external IP, left to the SSH button on your Compute Engine instances page.

      socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
      {
          socket.Emit("private message", "Hello. I'm connected!");

      });

      socket.On("private message", (data) =>
      {

          MessageBox.Show(data.ToString());
          socket.Disconnect();
      });
  ```
- Bam! As my server code was running on instance computer, I got the "New Connection from: bla:bla" message as soon as the client app connection function called, and then received the "private message" event emit also.

It was a rookie mistake on my side. First thing to make sure is that you are using the socket.io client libraries, otherwise it won't work. And second, you need to connect to your IP and port using http://, not ws:// or wss://.

Hope this helps someone in future who is struggling with such simple problem. Thanks to everyone else who did their best to help despite my lack of information.

Answer (score 1):

You say app engine listens for requests? WS requests or HTTP requests?

Some things I've noticed.

By default all ws urls should look like this `ws://104.197.217.126:65080` or simply `104.197.217.126:65080` unless the client library allows you to specify the port. I suggest maybe sticking to the default `port:6455`
at first.

Also you don't need to use GAE + CCE to run a ws server. Its far more straight forward just using GCE. You could run a single CGE instance just for ws.

But since you mentioned GAE im going to assume you used one of those "nodejs on app engine" tutorials to get started. The issue here is that currently this is currently in beta. App engine will create GCE instances to run the code but the code will only be accessible through the .appspot.com domain. So `myapp.appspot.com:65080` might work

I'm still unclear of architecture of your setup and if you **need** GAE, but other than that, the nodejs code seems fine and should work by itself.

I suggest using [Websocket.org](https://www.websocket.org/echo.html) to do some more testing if how you connect to the ws connection first.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: Hey Orane, thanks for your answer. I mainly followed this guide by google: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/real-time-gaming-with-node-js-websocket  which uses GAE and GCE both. And for the echo test, I'm getting ERROR: undefined on both my ip:port and domain:port. About the architecture, believe me even I don't understand it fully. I think googles guides are not best suited for beginners.

Comment: Also note that i'm open to any other working logic. It doesn't have to be both GAE and GCE. But for that, I need a detailed explanation and/or a tutorial/guide.

Comment: @OnurÇevik yea this is definitely not a beginner tutorial, it doesn't even give you much implementation details. But I see what the aim is now. Basically this tutorial uses app engine to server ONLY front end resources, so you can pretty much forget about this for now until you're ready to login users etc. Lets focus on the CGE+Nodejs. Which os did you deploy? (Ubuntu, debian...?)

Comment: Ubuntu. I kind of realized that I should not be using GAE, since my client won't be running on it. My client application is totally independent from the cloud in terms of running. it only uses compute engine for data storage. I literally have no interest in browser work.

Comment: @OnurÇevik lol yea. But it may be a good option for building out apis in the future since it scales so well...Let me test something and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

I ran some tests:

It seems as though socket.io was built specifically to run with socket.io client libraries. So trying to access the ws connection from a standard ws library will result in headache. This is because the actual socket.io Uri will resemble `ws://127.0.0.1:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1474301877690-0`

I've found a library built for socket.io but haven't tested it.

https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet

Alternatively however I was able to use standard ws libraries and the websocket node.js library to see something working.

try out https://github.com/websockets/ws